# Using OSIV in vaadin 24 in production

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, vaadin, vaadin24

Since updating the versions of Hibernate, Vaadin and a custom framework based on Vaadin of the application, many issues have appeared regarding Hibernate proxy and lazily loading, that weren't there before doing the update.

I have enabled spring.jpa.open-in-view in the application.properties, since this was explicitly disabled before, and it fixed a lot of the issues.

I was wondering if anyone working with Vaadin 20 or later, would discourage enabling spring.jpa.open-in-view on an application running on Vaadin 24 in production, and if so, why this would be the case?

I have only found some warnings regarding it slowing down performance a bit, but the way the custom framework based on Vaadin is set up, enabling OSIV seems like the most effective and efficient way of solving the issues at this moment.

Comment: Does that custom framework you did not name offer some data service abstraction layer on top of Hibernate? Just noting here that Vaadin itself has nothing and is totally agnostic regarding how you access data.

Comment: OSIV will not help with Vaadin. I wonder how it was possible that it worked before

Comment: What is the point, when it "fixes alot of the issues", but not all? OSIV is/was a band-aid in a vaadin application (it helped back in the V7/8 days so maybe still; but more likely by accident, as it prolongs the link to the session for the loaded objects across the borders of the servlet world), when your design has no barrier between DB and UI.  So the answer no one wants to hear is: fix your architecture.  Therefor I close-vote: neither the problems, that OSIV fixes are shown (I have a strong guess though) nor the remaining ones.